# Cannot remove a value from array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

this might be a very simple mistake but i dont know where my mistake is. i have this code, i'm trying to remove a slot from the array as the user already choose a slot. but it doesn't work. can anyone help?

```
slot = ['8 AM', '9 AM', '10 AM', '11 AM' , '12 AM' , '2 PM', '3 PM', '4 PM']
print "slot available:" , slot
print 'Choose your slot'
slotchoose = raw_input ("choose:") 
if slotchoose == '8 AM' :
    slot.remove ( '8 AM ' )
else :
    if slotchoose == '9 AM' :
        slot.remove ( '9 AM' )
    else :
        if slotchoose == '10 AM' :
            slot.remove ('10 AM')
        else :
            if slotchoose == '11 AM':
                slot.remove ('11 AM')
            else:
                if slotchoose == '12 AM':
                    slot.remove ('12 AM')
                else :
                    if slotchoose == '2 PM' :
                        slot.remove ('2 PM')
                    else :
                        if slotchoose == '3 PM':
                            slot.remove ('3 PM')
                        else :
                            if slotchoose == '4 PM' :
                                slot.remove ('4 PM')

print "Slot aavail :" , slot
```

here is sample of the output :

```
slot available: ['8 AM', '9 AM', '10 AM', '11 AM', '12 AM', '2 PM', '3 PM', '4 PM']
Choose your slot
choose:8 AM 
Slot aavail : ['8 AM', '9 AM', '10 AM', '11 AM', '12 AM', '2 PM', '3 PM', '4     PM']
```

the     "8 AM" shouldn't be there

Comment: Do you know about `elif`?

Comment: If you only work with small arrays, you can put the stuff you haven't chosen in a temp array and replace the first one.

And like tobias said, `elif` would be better than a lot of `if else`

Comment: Also, do you know that all this code can effectively be replaced with `if slotchoose in (some valid values): slot.remove(slotchoose)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `slot.remove ( '8 AM ' )` with

```
slot.remove ( '8 AM' )
```

you can make your code pythonic:

```
slot = ['8 AM', '9 AM', '10 AM', '11 AM' , '12 AM' , '2 PM', '3 PM', '4 PM']
print "slot available:" , slot
print 'Choose your slot'
slotchoose = raw_input ("choose:") 
if slothchoose in slot:
     slot.remove(slothchoose)   
print "Slot aavail :" , slot
```

Answer (score 2):

Is indeed a simple mistake: you put an extra space.

```
slot.remove ( '8 AM ' )
```

should be:

```
slot.remove ( '8 AM' )
```

Comment: The error would have been avoided had he used `slot.remove(slotchoose)`. And then it would have turned out that all the if / elses were the same, and could be removed :-)